# Google App for Business Gmail vs Classic Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps

We are in transition to move on to Google Apps. I and also my coworkers have been using Gmail for quite some time now. We imported email our company mail accounts in our Gmail and things work smoothly.

I created standard account for Google Apps for Business to give it a try before migrating to Premier Edition. But there are couple of thing bothering me. They did such a good work with classic Gmail. Especially with contact management and GUI is also very comfortable to work with. But in Google Apps for Business Gmail frontend is like Gmail 2 years ago. Is there any good reason for this? Will this stay this way? Because its really unorthodox to have classic Gmail for free with all these features and when you pay you are transported back to the past. I haven't tried Premier Edition but I guess it has the same user interface. Do any of you have insight in this topic?

Comment: This question is offtopic for this site. Try http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Lately, they updated stuff so the business gmail behaves and looks like the common one. You can switch between accounts of both regular and business with no effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me do some question necromancy. Google Apps Gmail is no longer behind "regular" Gmail.

BTW It has been behind with many other services, e.g. we just recently got Google+. But Google is unifying their architecture and the gap is shrinking.